# How would i go about adding text right next to a form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a description as to how to use the form directly next to the form.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
    <h1 class="form-inline" style="text-align: center;">Tester</h1>
      <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-5">
         <label for="FormControlInput1">Full Name</label>
         <input type="name" class="form-control" id="FormControlInput1" placeholder="John Doe">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label for="FormControlInput2">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="phone-number" class="form-control" id="FormControlInput2" placeholder="403-213-4312">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-5">
         <label for="FormControlTextarea1">Required Services</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" id="FormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
   </form>
```

Was hoping to be able to get the "tester" message to the right of the form.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Are you using a CSS framework like Bootstrap? Where do your classes like form-inline, form-row, col-md-5 etc. come from?

Comment: @Steve yeah im using bootstrap as the framework

Comment: @TheDemonicSky what did you mean about "message to the right of the form" does it mean the "tester" should be right aligned or it should be right side of all the elements? It would be great if you can share a screenshot of what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's [grid layout system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) to manage the layout.

For example:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="col">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="FormControlInput1">Full Name</label>
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="FormControlInput1" placeholder="John Doe">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="FormControlInput2">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="phone-number" class="form-control" id="FormControlInput2" placeholder="403-213-4312">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="FormControlTextarea1">Required Services</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="FormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <h1 class="col" style="text-align: center;">Tester</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This would create: 
 - A `container` to manage the layout
 - A `row` to manage the form and the h1 as elements that should be positioned next to each other
 - The `form` and the `h1` each marked with the `col` class so that they are auto laid out. You can also use different classes like `col-2` `col-md-2` etc. to have more control over how many columns each control is allowed to use.